# Align website as right to left

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is a new ASP.NET web application using vb.net 2010 
Now I need to change the direction of the whole site to right to left
so that the login view is aligned to the left and title to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See CSS attribute `direction`.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

The way I achieved this with my project was by using the LESS CSS compiler.  I created two variables: one called `PrimarySide` and one called `SecondarySide`.  In LTR languages those variables were `left` and `right` respectively; in RTL it was `right` and `left` respectively.

Then anywhere I was setting margin, padding, border, or float, or clear, which are things that I might set left and right styles for, I would use the @PrimarySide variable instead.  For example:
`float: @PrimarySide` instead of `float: left`

This let me swap out a few variables and compile new versions of my CSS without having to go through and change every location I was doing something with the left or right side.

If this isn't an option for you, then look for the above CSS styles I mentioned and make a RTL version of your CSS that effectively swaps all of their left and right values, set direction: rtl, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx?
It help you konow how to use resources in .net.